# How do I find the branch a branch requested to be merged into?

Tags: git

Basically, I have a branch that requested a merge on another branch and in Git I can see the branch that my first branch requested to be merged into.

```
Request to merge mybranch1 into mybranch2
```

Mybranch2 is not usually master and I don't know how to find that branch using Git commands. Is there a Git command that can help me achieve this?

Comment: Git branches don't request to be merged. This information is part of the system you build around/with Git, but Git branches don't care.

Answer (score 1):

You can see all the related branch that you have in local (ie on your computer) by doing `git branch`

Because you dont always have all the remote (thoses one on Git) branch on your local, you can see all the remote branch by doing `git branch -a`.

And you will be to see all the related branch to your repo and know wich one is your `master`
It will appear kind of like so :

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

The following commands would provide you all the branches for a particular repository:

```
git branch
```

e.g.

```
  λ git branch
      * master
```